# error: unnable to start activity android app

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-application

My application is an android app and its about an accelerometre,but whenever i try to lunch it it raises me the following error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.accelerometre, PID: 21688
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accelerometre/com.example.accelerometre.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2029)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #18: Duplicate id 0x7f080134, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:116)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:890)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:851)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1022)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:851)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
            at com.example.accelerometre.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:171)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7376)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7367)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3181)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3338)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2029)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

and here is my MainActivity file:

```
    package com.example.accelerometre;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.SensorAdditionalInfo;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    
    import com.example.accelerometre.R;
    
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.view.View;
    
    import androidx.navigation.NavController;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
    
    import com.example.accelerometre.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
    
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
        private long lastUpdate = 0;
        private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
        private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 600;
        private SensorManager senSensorManager;
        private Sensor senAccelerometer;
        private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
        private ActivityMainBinding binding;
        private void getRandomNumber() {
            ArrayList numbersGenerated = new ArrayList();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                Random randNumber = new Random();
                int iNumber = randNumber.nextInt(48) + 1;
    
                if(!numbersGenerated.contains(iNumber)) {
                    numbersGenerated.add(iNumber);
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_1);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(0));
    
                text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_2);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(1));
    
                text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_3);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(2));
    
                text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_4);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(3));
    
                text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_5);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(4));
    
                text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_6);
                text.setText(""+numbersGenerated.get(5));
    
                FrameLayout ball1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_1);
                ball1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                FrameLayout ball2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_2);
                ball2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                FrameLayout ball3 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_3);
                ball3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                FrameLayout ball4 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_4);
                ball4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                FrameLayout ball5 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_5);
                ball5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                FrameLayout ball6 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ball_6);
                ball6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_down_ball_first);
                ball6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball6.clearAnimation();
                ball6.startAnimation(a);
    
                ball5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball5.clearAnimation();
                ball5.startAnimation(a);
    
                ball4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball4.clearAnimation();
                ball4.startAnimation(a);
    
                ball3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball3.clearAnimation();
                ball3.startAnimation(a);
    
                ball2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball2.clearAnimation();
                ball2.startAnimation(a);
    
                ball1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ball1.clearAnimation();
                ball1.startAnimation(a);
            }
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            SensorAdditionalInfo sensorEvent = null;
            Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
    
            if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                float x = sensorEvent.floatValues[0];
                float y = sensorEvent.floatValues[1];
                float z = sensorEvent.floatValues[2];
                long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
                if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
                    long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                    lastUpdate = curTime;
                    float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/ diffTime * 10000;
    
                    if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                        getRandomNumber();
                    }
    
                    last_x = x;
                    last_y = y;
                    last_z = z;
                }
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    
        }
    
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            setContentView(binding.getRoot());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
    
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
            appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    
            binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
    
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                    || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    }
```

And this is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Accelerometre.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Accelerometre.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/ball_1"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/ball_2"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/ball_3"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/ball_4"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/ball_5"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/ball_6"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/blue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/number_6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my styling is in the themes file in the values folder:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Accelerometre" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Accelerometre.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Accelerometre.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Accelerometre.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

this is my probleme and I hope if someone figure out where exactly the problem is helps me with it  , and thanks

Comment: You've got a superfluous `setContentView()` call. Remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line.

Comment: thanks, but getting a whole other bunch of errors that I cant resolve am not familiar with mobile developpement with android: